# Intellij is puttign spaces inside the lines after the formatting

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I branch from the master and work there. Then when I put the format option, I have additional spaces inside lines that are done previously by other developers. The examples are provided below,

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I make sure that when I format in the source file, it won't include additional spaces inside the line wrote earlier by previous developers?

Thank you.

Comment: Applying a format is supposed to adjust the code to look a certain way. You can configure what way that is, e.g. to not use space around `=`, but them that is your format for all `=`. If you want to leaves code format unchanged, then don't apply formatting.

Comment: See: [Configuring code style - Help | IntelliJ IDEA - JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html)

Comment: Well, this doesn't sound well.  I mean 100% times I'm not happy the code I write and need to format them anyway and I can't do it only for the portions I wrote but the entire file.

Comment: I don't know if Intellij is the same but in Netbeans you can highlight the part of the file you want to format.

Comment: Same for Eclipse, if you highlight a section of code, you can reformat that section only.

Comment: Okay this may be the way to go. @mwarren this is very helpfult to know if we can partly format the codebase using the Intellij